# Laucning View from UIAlertView, and when new View Dismissed want original AlertView still visible

Tags: ios, view, uialertview, modalviewcontroller

I am using UIAlertView to let the user know some information, I have a button on the AlertView that when clicked triggers a whole new view to be shown.

The pseudo code run when the button is clicked is:

Find my UIViewController, and initiate the veiw controller for my new view, and call `presentModalViewController:mySecondView animated:Yes`

And this works fine..

On mySecondView I have a button that I use to dismiss the view using `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES`

Now, the transitions work, I click on the UIAlertView Button and the SecondView appears, and when I click on the Exit Button my original View appears, unfortunately it appears without the ALERTVIEW that started the transition..

I want the first view to reappear with the AlertView still visible, after all the user did not dismiss it.  So, what is the best way to go about this?  Have the button simply load the veiw from a nib, and add it to the subview of the parentview of alertview, and then hide it when the exit button is pushed?  Seems kludgy and boring, but I assume this would work...

Store the fact the alert view is visible in a modal variable, and on the ViewWillAppear check the modal, and then redraw the UIALERTVIEW?  This seems like a memory leak to me, since the original view was never explicitly released...

I got to believe there is a more elegant solution... any ideas anyone?

Comment: Have you considered UIActionSheet instead?

Comment: I have not, upon further investigation, looks like dismissal of the AlertView is default behavior for any button pushed.

I am investingating a slution: extend the UIAlertView class and overload the dismissWithClickedButtonIndex, to not dismiss the view, but then probably hide it set some flag in the controller, and when the view comes back to view one, check the flag and show it again.

Haven't ActionSheet, but I am presenting more information that just a title on the AlertView, so I am not sure if ActionSheet would be a reasonable equivalent. At times its a decent amount in the message.

Comment: It looks like subclass the UIAlerView is the way to do.  I found out about that the method you mentioned after I posted the comment.  So you are on the right track.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end I just wound up just recreating the alert view after the secondary view was dismissed.  I can't say I'm crazy about it, but it does provide the behavior I need without lots of hacking.